# Most efficient way to query SQL Server large table almost complete result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance, large-data

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 with a large number of rows. Let's call it TableA.

I need to query its PK (an AUTOINCREMENT ID, CLUSTERED KEY) for *almost* all the rows (let's say, 97% of the rows) and this result set is usually in join with another table (TableB) via foreign key (let's call it FK_A).

The query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    TableB.someColumnNotFKNorPK
FROM   
    TableB 
INNER JOIN 
    TableA ON TableB.FK_A = TableA.ID
WHERE  
    TableA.LowSparseColumn = 100
```

The problem is that `TableA` has 97% of the rows with `LowSparseColumn = 100`, therefore this yields to row spools etc. because SQL Server needs to stash the partial result

Do you know how to deal with such issue?

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Probably by [creating a filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes) on `LowSparseColumn=100`.

Comment: I don't think so filtered index will help here as 97% of the rows satisfies that criteria & one of the main considerations of creating filtered index should be relevant record should be minimal. may be simple non-clustered index on LowSparseColumn will improve the speed.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an index on `TableB(fk_A)` (or better yet (`TableB(fk_A, someColumnNotFKNorPK)` and your table statistics are up-to-date, then the optimizer should do its job.  It should read `TableA` and do a join to `TableB` without spooling.

You could rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT TableB.someColumnNotFKNorPK
FROM TableB 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TableA 
              WHERE TableB.FK_A = TableA.ID AND
                    TableA.LowSparseColumn = 100
             );
```

This should make optimal use of an index on `TableA(ID, LowSparseColumn)` (although that index is not necessary if `ID` is a primary key).